# security updates for embedded firmware Tomato (router)

Tags: linux, router, firmware, embedded-system

I installed on my Linksys router Tomato firmware.

I saw

[image]

and now don't understand how security updates work. It can't be that there is no vulnerability since 2010.

```
Tomato Firmware v1.28.1816
Copyright (C) 2006-2010 Jonathan Zarate
http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato/
Built on Sun, 27 Jun 2010 20:10:52 -0700
```

Comment: Several problems here. You assume that the firmware is still being maintained. If you read the wiki, you will see that there are forks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Development of the official Tomato firmware has indeed **been discontinued since 2010** with version 1.28 being the latest release.

Wikipedia has a nice [comparison table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_%28firmware%29#Feature_comparison) of various forks that have been created since then. Although it has a focus on Linksys routers, you can find current information on actively developed Tomato mods in [this forum](http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?forums/tomato-firmware.33/). The [AdvancedTomato](https://advancedtomato.com/) firmware (a fork from [Shibby mod](http://tomato.groov.pl/)) is one possible option with fairly frequent updates.

That said, I find it suspicious that Tomato seems to have a very short record of publicly known vulnerabilities. This could either be due to well-written code or indicate that there has not been a lot of auditing since then.